# How do we solve p xor 1 xor q? How to verify if the result is correct?

Tags: binary, equation, xor

What is the equation we get when we do `(p xor q xor 1)`

I know that `(p xor 1)` is p'

Is `(p xor q xor 1) = (p xor q')` or `(p' xor q')`?

Please help me. How do we verify these things?

Comment: This is unclear. What do you mean by "solve"?

Comment: I apologize. I mean verify.

Comment: If `p xor 1 = p'` then `p xor q xor 1 = q xor (p xor 1) = q xor p'` Also, it's equal to `p xor q'` and `(p xor q)'`.

Comment: Are both p xor q' and (p xor q)' the answers to this? Are they the same? How can I verify this?

Comment: you can solve (verify) boolean (binary) equations using boolean algebra which is mathematically defined. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about boolean logic / [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 1):

Since all the operators are the same, they will have the same priority so `(p xor q xor 1)` will be equivalent to this:

```
(p xor q)xor 1
```

which is equivalent to:

`(p xor q)'`

Answer (score 0):

How to verify this.

Let's build a [truth table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) and see how the results compares for another equation.

And [`p xor q xor 1`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=p+xor+q+xor+1) can be read as `(p xor q) xor 1`.
Of course we assume that 1 stands for true and 0 for false.

```
p   q   p xor q xor 1
0   0   1
0   1   0
1   0   0
1   1   1
```

This will give the same results as `p xnor q`

```
p   q   p xnor q    
0   0   1
0   1   0
1   0   0
1   1   1
```

`not(p xor q)` , `p xor not q` , `not(p) xor not(q)` will give the same results.